# Use of third-party RSS feeds 

Tags: rss, feed

I was wondering if there are any legal issues with using somebody else's RSS feed in your app (e.g. a BBC RSS feed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really should ask a lawyer. However, I found this on [out-law.com](http://www.out-law.com/page-7843):

> Using a third party RSS feed on your site
>
> Most providers of RSS feeds are happy
>   to have their feeds displayed on third
>   party websites. However, if you plan
>   to display adverts next to a third
>   party's RSS feed, or otherwise profit
>   from the feed, we recommend that,
>   ideally, you seek permission from the
>   provider.
>
> At the very least you should check the
>   sites whose feeds you want to use for
>   conditions of use for their RSS feeds
>   or, if there are no such conditions,
>   the site's copyright notice. Even in
>   the absence of any prohibition in
>   these notices, you're safest course of
>   action is to approach each site for
>   permission. That's not to say you'll
>   definitely get sued for following your
>   plan without permission from each
>   party; it's just that you run a risk.
>
> If conditions forbid commercial use of
>   a feed, request permission before
>   using the feed on anything other than
>   a personal website. Commercial use
>   does not only mean that you are
>   selling access to the feed or
>   surrounding the feed with advertising;
>   any use on the website of a business
>   can also be a commercial use.

Source:  http://www.out-law.com/page-7843